# JBoss EAP 6.3.0 Application save file to working folder

Tags: jboss, java-ee-6, java-6, jboss-eap-6

I am writing a application that will run inside JBoss EAP 6.3.1 on a CentOS 6.5

During this application i have to save a file to the disk and when restarting the application i have to read it back into the application.

All this is working.

The problem is that i want to save to file in the working directory of the application.

What is happening right now is that the file: foo.bar will be saved at the location where i run the standalone.sh (or .bat on Windows).

```
public void saveToFile() throws IOException {
    String foo = "bar";

    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/foo.bar"), "UTF-8");
    try {
        out.write(foo);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use an absolute path to save your file:

```
String yourSystemPath = System.getProperty("jboss.home.url") /*OPTIONAL*/ + "/want/to/save/here";
File fileToSave = new File(yourSystemPath,"foo.bar");  
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileToSave), "UTF-8");
```

Basically here, I'm creating a `File` object using a `yourSystemPath` variable where I stored the path to save the file in, then I'm creating the `new FileOutputStream(fileToSave)` using the previously created object `File`

Please ensure that your JBoss server has write permissions for `yourSystemPath`

Comment: This would be indeed the solution if i wanted to save the file at a fix place. I more would like to solution to write in the working directory where the application is running.

Comment: So what do you mean with "i want to save to file in the working directory of the application" ? Isn't always the same path?

Comment: Every application deployed on a JBoss server gets it's own working directory. When i would deploy the same application 4 times there should be 4 working directory's for each application one. The application have to stay within the boundaries of JBoss

Comment: Ok I got it... so, I think you can use the jboss constant to get the jboss root path with `System.getProperty("jboss.home.url")` to build your path, so this will work on every system/server. I modified my answer after comments

Comment: With your help i found this link to support it: [link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProperties)

Comment: Yes, that's it. As you can see you can relate to a lot of properties to get your path ;)